# Not Equal to one number or another number PHP != || together php

Tags: php, if-statement, operator-keyword

I'm trying to basically use if statement that says
`if ($_POST['mc_gross_1'] !=  '20' || $_POST['mc_gross_1'] !=  '19')`

which if it's not equal to 19 or 20 I give an error but it's not working.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `&&` or AND, not `||` or OR. OR is checking both values. A variable cannot be equal to two different numbers at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

You're using or instead of and. You're saying this:

if it isn't 20 or it isn't 19

which is basically always, since it can't be both 20 and 19 at the same time.